# How to get common column from multiple table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

In one of my application I need to get the **common columns** of tables.Suppose from  **NorthWind** database  I have two table **Order and OrderDetail** ,need to get the common columns of those tables Like:OrderID.Is there any sp or Mechanism or Script Who can do this for me.IF have any idea plz share with me.If have any query plz ask ,thanks in advance

Comment: Columns with the same data or the same name?

Comment: sll i need to know  Same name and same type columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me to find columns with the same name.

```
select a.column_name 
from information_schema.columns a
join information_schema.columns b on a.column_name = b.column_name and b.table_name = 'table1'
where a.table_name = 'table2'
```

---

To get FK information on order use this:

```
DECLARE @tab int

SELECT @tab = object_id FROM sys.tables WHERE NAME = 'order'

SELECT t.name as [Table], fkc.constraint_column_id, c.name as [Column] 
FROM sys.foreign_key_columns as fkc
INNER JOIN sys.tables as t on fkc.parent_object_id = t.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns as c on fkc.parent_object_id = c.object_id and fkc.parent_column_id = c.column_id
WHERE fkc.referenced_object_id = @tab
```

Comment: Hogan thanks for reply.I know aboutinformation_schema process  But problem is that in my database all tables don't have the Relation ship.They are connected but with out relation ship.If tables have no relation ship then information_schema not work.I don't know the technique How to get common table with out relation ship.by the bye thanks again

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "have no relation ship".  But you could try sys.syscolumns too -- just not as portable an answer.

Comment: I want to say physical relation Suppose in northwind Order and OrderDetails are physically connected ,when u delete the relation ship then you above syntax not work.u delete the relation ship from diagram but there are still logical connection.

Comment: @shamin - So you want to see what constraints the two tables have?

Comment: hogan ,thank for reply again.yes i want to see the constraints pk and fk